# Difference between 会う and 集まる

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I don't know exactly the difference between those two?
What are the most commons use for those ones?

For example, what are the difference between these sentences?

> 友達に会った
>
> 友達に集まった

Answer (score 6, accepted):

友達に集まった does not make any sense. It should be 友達が集まった. But even then the meaning is not the same.

会う : meet

集まる : gather

> 友達が集まった。 : my friends gathered
>
> 友達に会った。 : I met my friends

They aren't related at all.